# Constructor for a DOM element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is it possible to create a DOM element with a constructor using jquery?

I am trying to reverse-engineer a plug in called [h5p](https://h5p.org/tutorial-greeting-card), if you scroll down to the 'javascript' section you will see the following steps:

1. A declaration of a namespace for the object (I assume as to not pollute the global namespace
2. A consrtuctor function that creates the actual DOM element
3. Secondary helper functions that build the DOM element

I understand that this particular code is reliant on a framework, but is it possible for it to be replicated just in a single js file?

```
var H5P = H5P || {};

H5P.GreetingCard = (function ($) {
  /**
   * Constructor function.
   */
  function C(options, id) {
    // Extend defaults with provided options
    this.options = $.extend(true, {}, {
      greeting: 'Hello world!',
      image: null
    }, options);
    // Keep provided id.
    this.id = id;
  };

  /**
   * Attach function called by H5P framework to insert H5P content into
   * page
   *
   * @param {jQuery} $container
   */
  C.prototype.attach = function ($container) {
    // Set class on container to identify it as a greeting card
    // container.  Allows for styling later.
    $container.addClass("h5p-greetingcard");
    // Add image if provided.
    if (this.options.image && this.options.image.path) {
      $container.append('<img class="greeting-image" src="' + H5P.getPath(this.options.image.path, this.id) + '">');
    }
    // Add greeting text.
    $container.append('<div class="greeting-text">' + this.options.greeting + '</div>');
  };

  return C;
})(H5P.jQuery);
```

This is what I imagine (warning: rough pseudocode ahead!):

```
// quick and dirty h5p prototyping
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>import jquery here<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    // constructor for dom element

    // secondary helpers for dom element

    // initialize the element and append it to dom


  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <h2> h5p prototyping</h2>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly than you can create DOM elements using jQuery in this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var newDOM = $('<div/>', {
    class: 'new-dom',
    html: $('<span/>', {
      text: 'NEW DOM!!'
    }),
    onClick: 'alert("Works EVEN JS");'
  });

  $('body').append(newDOM);
});
```

```css
.new-dom {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Simply add required attributes of DOM element to second parameter of constructor object `$('<nodeName/>', {settingsObject})`.